# Spring boot UserNotFound message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to make basic authentication in spring boot (2.5.3), and call UserNotFoundException when cant found user at DB.

```
@Override
public User findByUserName(String username){

    try {

        return (User) template.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email = ?",
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(User.class), username);

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }
}
```

But as a result I get message "Bad Credential". My exception has changed by BadCredential Exception.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    //HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put(
            "timestamp",
            Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    data.put(
            "exception",
            ex.getMessage());

    System.out.println(ex.getClass());

    response.getOutputStream()
            .println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
}
```

class org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException

What should I override to make ability to see UserNotFoundException error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the `AuthenticationProvider` to throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` instead of a `BadCredentialsException` when the username is not found.

Be aware that this is considered **less secure**.

From the `setHideUserNotFoundExceptions` Javadoc:

> By default the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` throws a `BadCredentialsException` if a username is not found or the password is incorrect. Setting this property to `false` will cause `UsernameNotFoundException`s to be thrown instead for the former. Note this is considered less secure than throwing `BadCredentialsException` for both exceptions.

If you choose to do this, below is an example of how to use `setHideUserNotFoundExceptions`

```java
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(customPasswordEncoder);
    provider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false) ;
    return provider;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make custom Auth provider

```
    public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User user = repository.findByUserName(name);

        if(!encoder().matches(password, user.getPassword())){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password,
                        Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER_ROLE")));
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Like there explained https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider